# Slide show, slide effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slide show .....

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var image1=new Image()
    image1.src="slide-image-1.png"
    var image2=new Image()
    image2.src="slide-image-2.png"

    //-->
    </script>

<img name="slide" class="image1" src="slide-image-1.png" />
<script>
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<2)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",4000)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
```

I want to change the way in which the slides replace each other by horizontally scrolling right to left (i hope this makes sense). What would this type of transition be called please? Could it be done by a simple few lines?

(I know this is probably a easy thing for a experienced web designers but ive only just started and not sure as to what this would be)

Comment: First of all, don't use `eval`. You don't need it and it's bad practice.

Comment: im sorry what is eval please ??

Comment: +1, eval isn't even necessary there if you restructure it into an array.

Comment: This code has just been taken from an online tutorial website to learn from. It did the job, apart from the effect. If the coding is bad then i apologise. Like i said, im new to this, we all have to learn somewhere,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to do this. You can find a number of plug-ins [here](http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jquery to get such effect i have added pseudo code for animation of two divs

```
<body>
    <div id="divone" style="background-color:#808080;width:150px;height:250px;"></div>
    <div id="div1" style="background-color:#0026ff;width:150px;height:250px;display:none;"></div>
    <script>
        //jQuery("#divone").animate({ opacity: 0.10 }, 5000);
        //jQuery("#divone").fadeOut(5000);
        jQuery("#divone").fadeOut(5000, function () { jQuery("#div1").fadeIn(5000) })
    </script>
</body>
```